# Crossfilter: how to build custom reduce functions when I want to access a specific array-value?

Tags: crossfilter

I have constructed my crossfilter-setup a bit different than in most examples I can find, namely:

I have data-array d with multiple data-sources included, among which is data1.

```
var cf = crossfilter(d3.range(0, d.data1.length));
```

Then I construct my dims like:

```
var dim = cf.dimension(function(i) { return d.data1[i].id; });
```

And I construct my groups like:

```
var group = dim.group().reduceSum(function(i) { return d.data1[i].total;});
```

This all works fine, but when I want to create custom reduce functions, the extra parameter i is giving me trouble.

```
var reduceAddPerc = function(p,v) {
    p.sumOfSub += d.data1[i].var1;
    p.sumOfTotal += d.data1[i].total;
    p.finalVal = p.sumOfSub / p.sumOfTotal;
    return p;
};
var reduceRemovePerc = function(p,v) {
    p.sumOfSub -= d.data1[i].var1;
    p.sumOfTotal -= d.data1[i].total;
    p.finalVal = p.sumOfSub / p.sumOfTotal;
    return p;
};
var reduceInitialPerc = function() {
    return {sumOfSub:0, sumOfTotal:0, finalVal:0 };
};
```

And then defining the group with:

```
var group = dim.group().reduce(reduceAddPerc,reduceRemovePerc,reduceInitialPerc);
```

This doesn't work obviously, since the parameter i is now not known within the function. But I've tried adding the parameter (p,v,i), or nesting the functions by creating an additional function with parameter i around the (p,v) function, and also creating an additionao function(i) within the (p,v) function, but I cannot get this to work.

Does anyone have any help to offer?

Comment: BTW - not directly related to your question, but you should compute p.finalVal in your visualization and not in your custom reducer for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In the custom reduce functions, the `v` parameter is the record currently being "reduced". In this case, it should be your counter, so just use it where you would normally use `i`. Is that not working?